# Creating SQL Server custom EKM Cryptographic Provider DLL

Tags: sql-server, encryption, dll, cryptography, tde

This is a long shot, but here goes. I am trying to create a custom SQL Server EKM Cryptographic Provider DLL as referenced [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-cryptographic-provider-transact-sql).

The problem is that nowhere can I find any reference on how to create the DLL. 
I came across a discussion from several years ago that referenced creating a [sample DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Unfortunately that now leads to a "Content Removed" page.

Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

Alas, Microsoft doesn't make the ekm spec public
you have to enter into an NDA with them.

Comment: I did manage to track down the right person. Signed the NDA and got the SDK.

Comment: @NeilWeicher could you share the person contact?